# kubectl - error: You must be logged in to the server

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm

I have configured OIDC with k8s installed using kubeadm.
After the configuration, when I run the command `kubectl --user=name@gmail.com get nodes` I get

> error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials (get nodes))

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

I use `kubectl --username=name@gmail.com get nodes` and it works. Earlier I was using the parameter `--user` instead of `--username`.

Comment: --user is the correct parameter. --username is ignored, which means you may have been falling back to a default user that does not use oidc.

Answer (score 0):

Your password is probably missing.

Comment: I have added the client_id, client_secret, id_token and refresh token to my /.kube/config file. Where do i need to add my password? Could you please let me know. It would be really helpful

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert with kub, (but in openshift you should log with user, passwd) but `--password="":` might help. Please refer to: https://kubernetes-v1-4.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_config_set-credentials/

Comment: Cloud you please tell me if i can add a role with the user and the password with K8S?

Comment: Should the user be explicitly registered for this? I meant to ask if kubectl config set-context and set-credentials is required for this.